# Firestore historical usage document reads, writes, deletes

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to retrieve historical firestore usage beyond 30 days? "Last 30 days" seems to be largest time frame.  I'm looking for read, write, delete counts a couple months ago.  Surely, there's a way?

Comment: There is not.  Contact Firebase support and file a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

As Doug commented, the report in the Firebase/Firestore console is limited to the last 30 days.

What you **can** already do yourself is enable [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/release-notes#September_02_2021) on the operations you're interested in, and then keep them as long as you want in Cloud Logging, or aggregate them out of there into your own reporting structure. Also see the Firestore documentation on [audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging).

Comment: Thank you kindly, Frank.  It looks like you might be able to do this with Cloud Monitoring as well - I've almost got it but it just doesn't quite sum by entire days (splits them into 3hr intervals).  While it does show data > 30 days, there appears to be a hard data retention stop there also around mid September, so maybe not.  I'll look into the audit logs... and take regular screenshots. :)

Comment: Default retention in Cloud Logging may indeed be limited, but you should be able to extend that (at an increased cost) as far as I know (definitely not an expert on this part).